# How do I get MS Project to give "Actual Finish" using a new baseline?

Tags: ms-project, pm-software, ms-project-2007

I have a schedule baselined in MS Project 2007. We have identified, documented and obtained approval for a change to this schedule. I plan to save the new baseline as "Baseline 1" and keep the original schedule as "Baseline", the idea is to better show at a glance the evolution of the schedule with MS Project rather than have to look at the schedule together with the change documentation.

Additional columns that I have are "Actual Finish" and "Finish Variance". By default "Finish Variance" equales "Actual Finish" minus "Baseline Finish". Is there any way to change this so that my "Finish Variance" column corresponds to "Actual Finish" minus "Baseline 1 Finish"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File, Options, Advance.  Under Earned Value Options For This Project, change the calculation field to Baseline 1.  All EV, as well as other variance calculations, should then calculate from Baseline 1 instead of baseline.